# Сортировка данных в функции gql из @apollo/client

Tags: запрос, nextjs, graphql, apollo-client

Столкнулся с проблемой. Проект на NextJS и там используется библиотека @apollo/client. У меня есть запрос вида:

```
export const GET_USERS = gql`
    query User($uid: Int){
        users(pagination: { limit: -1 }, sort: "guid, uid", filters: {uid: {eq: $uid}}){
            data{
            ....
```

где guid и uid - целочисленные поля. И пользователи получаются по возрастанию, что и очевидно. Мне нужно, чтобы сортировка была по убыванию, т.е. от большего значения в guid к меньшему.
Пробовал разные варианты и
`sort: "guid desc, uid"`
`sort: "guid(desc), uid"`
`sort: "guid: desc, uid"`
и так далее.
Пробовал использовать sorts, sortBy, order, orderBy, на них ругается, что неизвестные аргументы.
Пробовал в sort поместить объект, ругается, говорит, что ожидался тип string.

Как сделать сортировку по убыванию для поля guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось гениально простым:
Вариант `sort: "guid: desc, uid"` был ближе всего. Правильный вариант: `sort: "guid:desc, uid"`, т.е. после : пробел не нужен...